# Pass a character vector in the by in data.table statement with a function

Tags: r, data.table

How can I aggregate the dates column per month and date?

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(dates = c('2017-01-01', '2017-01-05'))

chosen_col <- 'dates'
```

Tried the following which does not work:

```
df[, .(n = .N), by =  str_sub(chosen_col, 1, 7)]
df[, .(n = .N), by =  eval(str_sub(chosen_col, 1, 7))]
```

EDIT:

So the question is how do I pass a character vector to a function inside the by argument. Fully aware of workarounds for the date problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get()`:

```
df[, .(n = .N), by =  substring(get(chosen_col), 6)]

   substring n
1:     01-01 1
2:     01-05 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `get` to use `chosen_col` as a column name.

```
library(data.table)
#Convert to actual date
df[, (chosen_col) := as.Date(get(chosen_col))]
#Separate into month and date
df[, c('month', 'date') := list(format(get(chosen_col), "%m"), 
                                format(get(chosen_col), "%d"))]

#Count number of rows for each month and date
df[, .(n = .N), .(month, date)]
```

Comment: data.table also has functions wday() and month() (which could be used instead of format).